# Creating and showing dictionary from two arrays in js not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I know there are many posts out there that answer my question, but for some reason that I cannot figure out, I never end up with the desire result.

Here is my code:

```js
const NameArray = [];
const IdArray = [];
let Dict = {};

function getName() {
  const Input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const list_names = Input.split(", ");

  for (let i of list_names) {
    NameArray.push(i);
    IdArray.push(i);
  };
  console.log(NameArray, IdArray);
};

function CreateDict() {
  NameArray.forEach((key, i) => Dict[key] = IdArray[i]);
  console.log(Dict);
};

CreateDict();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick="getName();">Get Data</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am almost sure this simple code should work properly, but in my console log I do not see the array.
I’m working with Firefox, the latest version.

what I get is the following:

```
Object {  }
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
​​
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
​​
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
​​
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
​​
__proto__: 
​​
constructor: function Object()
​​
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
​​
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
​​
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
​​
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
​​
toString: function toString()
​​
valueOf: function valueOf()
​​
<get __proto__()>: function __proto__()
​​
<set __proto__()>: function __proto__()
```

It is problematic because I cannot debug, and I don’t even know how to access the key value pairs then...

Comment: You are calling `CreateDict();` while `NameArray` and `Dict` are still empty. Try and put `CreateDict();` inside the `getName()` function at end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have imported script file in your html file.
This makes your `CreateDict()` function run even before you type in input field.
`CreateDict()` function should only be run only after once getName() is invoked.
Ideal way will be :

```js
const NameArray = [];
const IdArray = [];
let Dict = {};

function getName() {
  const Input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const list_names = Input.split(", ");

  for (let i of list_names) {
    NameArray.push(i);
    IdArray.push(i);
  };
  console.log(NameArray, IdArray);
  CreateDict();
};

function CreateDict() {
  NameArray.forEach((key, i) => Dict[key] = IdArray[i]);
  console.log(Dict);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="input">
      <button onclick="getName();">Get Data</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```